# express 3 file upload: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multipartform-data

I am following [this tutorial](http://jsrecipes.org/#!/backend/uploading-files) on uploading a file. I have an express 3 server with some config. The `express.multipart` is giving me a `Error: Cannot find module 'readable-stream'` when I fire everything up

server config:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.multipart({ uploadDir: __dirname + '/uploads', limit: '50mb' }))
```

route:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
   console.log(req.files.file.name + ' has been uploaded')
   res.send(200)
})
```

html markup:

```
<form action='/upload' method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
    <input type='file' name='file'>
    <input type='submit' class='btn btn-default' value='Upload'>
</form>
```

I am using `node v0.10.29` and `npm 1.4.14`. What's the minimum express config for handling a file upload? Or is this a problem with my environment?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

express config:

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.bodyParser({ uploadDir: path.join(__dirname + '/uploads'), keepExtensions: true }))
```

route:

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
    var fileName = req.files.fileName.name,
        filePath = req.files.fileName.path;

    console.log(fileName + ' added to uploads')

    // Do something with file here:
    // - save metadata to database
    // - upload file to S3 bucket

    // remove file from our server
    fs.unlink(filePath, function(err){
        console.log(fileName + ' has been deleted!')
    })
    res.redirect('/')
}
```